# Snapping points to nearest road

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a small table of 10 cities (in one table) that I am snapping to the nearest road (in another table) with the following select and storing the table snapped_cities:

```
Select b.id, ST_Closestpoint(ST_Collect(a.geom), b.geom) as geom
into snapped_cities
from roads a inner join cities b
on ST_Dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 1000)
group by b.id;
```

I would however like to have road ids and not just the geom (`a.id` above). How do I modify the select above to get these?

I use postgresql 9.2 and postgis 2.0

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(b.id) b.id as id_city, a.id as id_road, a.geom
FROM roads a INNER JOIN cities b
ON ST_DWithin(b.geom, a.geom, 1000)
ORDER BY b.id, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom);
```

It's probably also possible to use st_closestpoint, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: see st_closestpoint in http://blog.jordogskog.no/2010/02/07/how-to-use-the-new-distance-related-functions-in-postgis-part1/, I use theses sample - it's work. Try change "group by b.id;" to "group by b.id, b.geom;"

Comment: I have indeed used that blog already. Including b.geom in the group by clause doesn't help on my problem - I want the a.id. I think the problem is that st_closestpoint() finds the closest POINT (of course!) where I want the closest road ID.